# Book: Springer "Grundwissen Mathematikstudium" English Language Alternative

Tags: book-recommendation

This is a rigorous and extremely comprehensive presentation of Linear algebra and Analysis in German language. Can anyone recommend such a comprehensive book in English Language?
https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-8274-2309-2

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, is it? There any lots of questions asking for book recommendations and a specific tag [book-recommendation].

Comment: @lhf I think that this is not a question of that sort. It's much more specific than that: is there a textbook in English which is similar to a certain German textbook?